# Classes e escopo de variáveis php

Tags: php, classes, escopo-de-variáveis

Veja bem, minha dúvida é mais sobre como fazer referencia e "obter" o conteúdo de uma variável em uma Classe PHP. Veja trechos do código abaixo, onde eu coloco dados errados para a conexao, de propósito, para provocar uma excecao do PDO, e assim armazenar a msg de erro na variável msgErro. Até ai, tudo bem, só que depurando o código (com XDebug), vejo que no arquivo que tem a classe e a variável msgErro, ela é criada numa boa, eu visualizo seu conteúdo (que é o erro de conexao), porém, quando a depuracao avança, e volta para o PHP do cadastro, que olho para o depurador, este mostra as variáveis locais, no caso o objeto que pegou as propriedades da classe, mas o valor da propriedade (variável) $u->msgErro está vazia (esvaziou)! e é isso que nao consigo entender como ela fica vazia, se uma linha antes, nas variáveis do arquivo usuarios.php, onde fica a classe, estava com conteúdo.

arquivo cadastrar.php
.
.

```
    $u->conectar("xxxx","xxxx","xxx","");
    if ($u->msgErro == "")
```

arquivo usuarios.php   // que contem a classe

```
Class Usuario 
{
    private $pdo;
    public $msgErro; //tudo ok

    public function conectar($nome, $host, $usuario, $senha){
            global $pdo;
            try 
            {
                $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$nome.";host=".$host,$usuario,$senha);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                $msgErro = $e->getmessage();
            }
    }
}
```

Quando eu testo a variavel $msgErro no arquivo cadastrar, através do objeto $u = new Usuario;

```
        if ($u->msgErro == "") 
    {
        echo "esta mensagem ´é se msgErro está vazia!";
```

Ou seja, nesse teste, deveria haver uma negativa do if, pois houve erro na conexao, o erro foi colocado na variavel $msgErro lá no arquivo usuarios.php, porém, no teste do arquivo cadastrar.php, a variável esta vazia, por isso passa direto pelo if. Alguma dica? grato.

Comment: A melhor dica mesmo é ficar esperto, se vc se dedicar muito mesmo a aprender a programar, vai perceber que quase todo "professor" de PHP não entende porcaria nenhuma de programação, e que quase sempre, usar OO em PHP pode ser considerado ignorância. Eu sei que se vc perguntar por aí vão dizer que é absurdo, mas é aquela coisa, depende  do quanto você realmente quer ser programador. Se tiver um tempo, aprenda a programar com C, C++, C#, e até mesmo Java. Aí vai ficar mais fácil de aprender de verdade, pq nessas linguagens mais sérias o pessoal não consegue fingir que tá programando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer se referir ao membro da classe, e não a uma variável qualquer, precisa deixar explícito:

```
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $this->msgErro = $e->getmessage();
}
//    ^
//    |
//     --------- O $this se refere à instância atual do objeto.
//               se fosse membro estático seria self::membro
//               (o self faz bypass na vtable do objeto,
//               definitivamente acessando a implementação original)
```

Veja dando erro :) no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/xQpyuq)**, conforme esperado.

Não que tenha relação com o problema original, mas veja a "salada" de escopos que está fazendo com `$pdo`:

```
private $pdo;
public $msgErro; //tudo ok

public function conectar($nome, $host, $usuario, $senha){
   global $pdo;
   try 
   {
      $pdo 
   ...
```

Não está usando `$this`, tem um global sobrando, e ainda um private.

Se quer fazer o OO "certinho", e precisar reusar o PDO (não parece ser seu caso), injete o PDO no construtor ou via método, se não for por esse caminho faça uma subclasse (eu não gosto, mas é melhor que global), mas não dependa de globais. Perde todo o sentido.

Comment: Bacco, ótima dica (deu certo aqui, colocando a pseudo-variável $this). Agora, por gentileza, explique: poderia usar também, neste caso, a outra pseudo-variável self:: ? e como seria? pois tentei self:: msgerro = $e->getmessage(); mas deu erro: 
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TELA DE LOGIN\CLASSES\usuarios.php on line 16.  PS: muito grato mesmo!

Comment: O self:: normalmente você vai usar quando tiver membros estáticos apenas, é bom uma lida da parte de classes do próprio manual do php. https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/index.php